# JQuery - disable false and reset value from an input using css class and .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a function but the alerts that i put in my each loop are not displayed. This function has to `disabled:false and .val("")` every input with a specific class. The function is working but the problem is that the function is not going in the each loop and i dont know why. The first alert() is executed but not the second.

The function :

```
function resetNivPrep(){
    alert("test");
    // Déclaré
    //LDQL
    $(".5001").each(function(){
        alert("test1");
        $(this).attr('disabled',false);
        $(this).val("");
    });
};
```

The HTML :

```
 <div id="tableNiveau" class="declare">
<table id="tableNivPrep" class="tabData" border="0" style="display:block">
    <thead>
        <tr class="entete">
            <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete">Préparation</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="entete">Déclaré</th>
                                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete">Option</th>
                                                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="entete" style="width:20%">Offre grand compte</th>
                        </tr>
        <tr class="entete">
            <th class="entete">Exemplaires</th>
            <th class="entete">Paquets</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Edition LDQLChoix de l'option

```
function traitementPublissimo(){
//PECTMA - 563 - Nico ( grâce a chithakone )
var nivServ = $('#niv_service_const').val();
var idContrat = $('#num_contrat_const').val();
idContrat = idContrat.replace(/\s+/g, '');
var numCppap = $('#num_cppap').val();
var strNumCppap = numCppap.substr(0,3);
// Ajax
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/gestion/gestDepot/ajaxgetnumcontrat",
    data:  {idContrat: idContrat},
    async : false,
    success : function(result){
        var reponse = $.parseJSON(result);
        var str = JSON.stringify(reponse);
        console.log(str);
            if(strNumCppap == "AIP"){
            resetNivPrep();
            // Déclaré
            $("#exemplaire_50001_0").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_50002_0").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_50003_1").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#paquet_50003_1").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_50004_0").attr('disabled',true); 
            $("#exemplaire_50005_0").attr('disabled',false);
            // Constaté
            $("#exemplaire_const_50001_0").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_const_50002_0").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_const_50003_1").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#paquet_const_50003_1").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_const_50004_0").attr('disabled',true);
            $("#exemplaire_const_50005_0").attr('disabled',false);
            }
```

How i trigger the action :

```
$( "#num_cppap" ).focusout(function() {
   traitementPublissimo();
 });   

 $( "#niv_service_const" ).focusout(function() {
   traitementPublissimo();
 });

 $( "#num_contrat_const" ).focusout(function() {
   traitementPublissimo();
 });
```

Comment: What's the HTML where this JS should be executed upon?

Comment: Topic edited @cloned

Comment: The PHP is not relevant at all, we would need to know the HTML that's getting rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$("#exemplaire_50005_0").attr('disabled',false);`

use `$("#exemplaire_50005_0").removeAttr('disabled');`

Everywhere